# How to store and access values stored in a Session Object on separate form pages

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am beginning to learn about Session Objects and I have come across an issue which I am sure is very simple.

I thought the idea of a session object was to store a variable so that it could be accessed later? In the below abated piece of code the first print statement works as expected printing "This is self request 2" but the second causes this error:

> Exception Type:   KeyError
>
> Exception Value:   0
>   Exception Location:   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py
>   in **getitem**, line 47

Why is the second print statement not working? Why can I not access `self.request.session[0]` on the second step of my form?

Any help/tips are much appreciated

Thanks

**Code**

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):    

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9']:
            step = int(self.steps.current)

            if step in (5, 6, 7):

                self.request.session[0] = 2   
                print 'This is self request', self.request.session[0]                 

            elif step == 8:                   

                print 'This is STILL self request', self.request.session[0]

        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use keys to store values:

```
request.session['fav_color'] = 'red' #Set the value
fav_color = request.session.get('fav_color', 'red') #Read the value else read a default one
```

From [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#bundled-serializers): A wrapper around the JSON serializer from django.core.signing. Can only serialize basic data types.

In addition, as JSON **supports only string keys**, note that using non-string keys in `request.session` won’t work as expected